# Understanding prediction interval for normal distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, predictive-models

I try to learn prediction intervals for normal distribution , so i found *[this wikipedia source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#cite_note-5)*. Everything was okey until i came to the case where the population mean is known but population variance is unknown. It is said that

> Solving for ${\displaystyle X_{n+1}}$ gives the prediction distribution ${\displaystyle sT^{n-1}}$, from which one can compute intervals as before.

However , I could not derive an interval  using this information . Hence , I want to learn what formula is used for prediction intervals for normal distribution when the population mean is known but not population variance.

Comment: +1. The notation (which you quote correctly) is awful, because the superscript $n-1$ refers to the *degrees of freedom* in a Student $t$ distribution, not a power!  It is also important to mention that $s^2$ is the sample variance.  Finally, be aware that the Wikipedia method is substandard because it should not base the interval on the sample variance, but on the raw second moment about the known mean. (Its disclaimer about being "more conservative" is both misleading and incorrect.)

Comment: @whuber thanks for upvoting.. ""more conservative" is both misleading and incorrect." , then what is the correct one ?

Comment: @whuber can we say that it is the same as the case where both mean and variance is unknown ?

Comment: @BruceET well , i have read it..and it seems that mean known sd unknown and both unknown are equal .. am i right ?

Comment: Sorry. My deleted Comment had a typo. Follow @whuber's lead.